# Impossible to log into admob account

Tags: authentication, admob

I am facing a strange login problem with admob and could not find any explanation for this exact problem on the web. So here is the problem:
- I have an admob account
- I jave an app link to that account
- The app released on the app store was perfectly displaying ads
- But 3 or 4 days after this, it became impossible to log in to my admob account. At the same time, the app had stopped displaying the ads.
- Each time I try to log in, the admob web page is telling me that "You are currently signed in as charlesdurandjp@gmail.com, which already has an AdMob account."
- When I click on the blue button "SIGN IN WITH CURRENT ACCOUNT", I simply remain on the same page.
I followed the admob help instructions (logging off from gmail etc.) but no success. I sent an email to admob support 3 days ago, but no answer.
I did not receive any email from admob stating there is any problem with my account or with my app.
In short, I am purely lost.
If anyone experienced such problem, I would love to hear about and / or to know if there any thing I could try to solve the issue.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your admob account is suspended or terminated. You should check your emails.

In the meanwhile you can start exploring Facebook Audience Network Ads to not loose any revenue.

http://hackerseve.com/android-using-together-admob-and-facebook-audience-network/
http://hackerseve.com/android-integrating-facebook-audience-network-fan/

Comment: Thank you for the insiight. I checked my email including spam but nothing. I wonder if it is because my app does not not have any in app purchase yet... Will have a look on Facebook Audience Ads.

Comment: I finally got an email from admob saying my account had been suspended for 1 month and it was available again.... well, will not use admob anymore!

Comment: AdMob is ridiculous. Blocking my account without any explanation why. Very unrelyable.